# redux-form Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, redux, redux-form

"Element type is invalid" I still keep getting this error and don't know what to do. Tried `<form>` and `<Form>` still same. Please help:
This is my AzForm.js saved at: "./components/testComponent"

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Container, Content, Text, Form } from 'native-base';
//import { createStore } from 'redux'  //NOT sure whether I need it, but I still get the same error
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const SignInForm = props => {
    return (
      <Form>
      </Form>
    );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple' // a unique identifier for this form
})(SignInForm)
```

and this is an extract from index.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';
import { SignInForm } from "./components/AzForm";

export class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SignInForm />
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change

`export class HomeScreen`

to

```
export default class HomeScreen`
```

When you export without the `default`, the component that is exported becomes what is known as a named export (you can have many of these per file). You would import these as `import {HomeScreen} from 'HomeScreen'`

The React convention is to one component per file. This is achieved by using the export default option as provided above. You would then import it using `import HomeScreen from 'HomeScreen';`